# Get values of same field from two users in same row output. Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have table `complains`, where columns are `id,complainant_id,defendant_id`.
I can get `phone` of complainant from `users` table in Model:

```
DB::table('complains')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'complains.complainant_id')
```

How can I send(make correct join) to a blade the `phone` of defendant and display it in `foreach`?